# Apache Ignite : Hibernate 5 2nd level cache

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ignite

I am trying to do a poc on using apache ignite as hibernate 2nd level cache, following the example given [here](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v2.1/docs/hibernate-l2-cache#maven-configuration). Since we are using Hibernate 5 in Spring Boot, I need to use ignite-hibernate_5.3. Unfortunately this artifact id is not present in any public maven repository, hence as mentioned [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/maven-setup#) i need to build it locally and push it to my maven repository.

When I am trying to build using the command

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Plgpl -pl modules/hibernate-5.3 -am
```

I am getting the error

The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018, org.jacorb:jacorb-idl:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018

I am not seeing any reference to the org.jacorb:jacorb , org.jacorb:jacorb-idl in any pom nor is it available in any public repository. This is happening for both 2.8.1 tag and also current SNAPSHOT What should be done to fix it, or is there some public repository where is can get ignite-hibernate_5.3?

Comment: Just a thought, if it's not principal for you to use Ignite, you can check out GridGain Community Edition. GridGain releases hibernate artifacts to Maven for that edition and you can use them freely.

Comment: I can check the GridGain community edition for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just built it from the 2.8.1 source, and it built OK.

Comment: what version of maven do you have? what are the maven repositories configured?

Comment: `Apache Maven 3.6.3`, no repositories configured explicitly.

Comment: i have 3.6.3 and also configured external repositories https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and https://gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external but still the issue. ANyway i am now working with gridgain hibernate-5.3 as suggested by @dmagda